# Entity Framework Core - error:Keyword not supported: 'server'

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, temporal-tables

I am using Entity Framework Core 7.1.  When I try to get the data from one of the db tables, I get the below error:

> "keyword not supported for 'fatqtyfkag.database.windows.net; initial catalog

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Linq;

namespace Emp.Data
{
    public class EmpDataContext : DbContext
    {       
        public DbSet<DisplayAPIDataEmployee>? DisplayAPIDataEmployees {get; set;}

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("server"); ;
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<DisplayAPIDataEmployee>().ToTable("Employees", e => e.IsTemporal());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please share the connectionstring

Comment: Based on the error message, could you have omitted `Server=` from the beginning of the connection string?

Comment: @letsdoit "Servername; Initial Catalog = Databasename; user id = Id; password=database password"

Comment: @AlwaysLearning not working :(

Comment: Is that the connection string you're using? Where's the `Server=` at the beginning? Ref: [SqlConnection.ConnectionString Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring)

Comment: @vw96 it should be `"Data Source=Servername; Initial Catalog = Databasename; user id = Id; password=database password"`